# How to remove HREF attribute from anchor tag in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have the following render function. It creates a hyperlink when the component has a URL and leaves it empty otherwise.

```
render: function() {
    var url = this.state.url;
    if (url) {
        return <a href={url}>{this.props.children}</a>
    } else {
        return <a>{this.props.children}</a>
    }
},
```

The problem is that once the HREF attribute has been set, React won't remove it. The else clause would lead to a tag that looks like this: `<a data-reactid=".0.1" href="">`.

I know I could just use a SPAN tag instead of A. For consistency sake though I would rather not.

Comment: `<a>` elements must have either an `href` attribute or a `name` attribute. What you are creating is simply invalid.

Comment: "If the href attribute is not specified, the element represents a placeholder hyperlink." http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a

Comment: I stand corrected. This is the interesting part: *"The name attribute on the a element is obsolete. Consider putting an id attribute on the nearest container instead."*

Answer (score 1):

You could have the href be set to # and then add an onClick handler for it that has `e.preventDefault()` as the only thing for it. I would just use the span approach though.